# Belief before 30 CE, that a prophet other than the Messiah or Elijah would appear?

Tags: sources-mekorot, history, messiah, messianic-redemption

Was there a Jewish belief prior to 30CE that a prophet other than Elijah would appear along with the Messiah?

If so, what evidence is there for it, what were the details of this belief, what documents is/was it in, and who believed it?

The question seeks evidence from 30CE or earlier and not later.

Comment: In I Kings 18:16, Ahab had been told where to meet the prophet Elijah, and he went there, expecting him to appear there, and he did. That's not an snwer, as you seek someone other than Elijah. But aside from that, is it the kind of answer you seek? If not, please [edit] to clarify your question.

Comment: Do YOU have any basis for raising this question?

Comment: No, the Pharisees in the first century CE were apparently expecting “the Prophet” to appear and asked John if he was it.  And that is already in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a belief in some circles of multiple types of messiah. The community living in [Qumran](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qumran) make reference to the coming of נביא ומשיחי אהרון וישראל, "the prophet and the messiahs of Aaron and Israel" ([Community Rule/1QS, column 9 line 11](https://archive.org/stream/TheDeadSeaScrollsStudyEditionMartinezTigchelaar1999/_The%20Dead%20Sea%20Scrolls%20Study%20Edition%2C%20Mart%C3%ADnez-Tigchelaar%201999#page/n115)).

The article "[The Endtime Return of Elijah and Moses at Qumran](https://www.jstor.org/stable/4193274)" argues for Moses (or a prophet in the role of Moses) being the prophet expected to come with the Messiah at Qumran, the source for the belief probably being Deuteronomy 18:15, which promises a prophet "like me" (Moses), and may have been interpreted messianically. Elijah would have been the priest-type "Messiah of Aaron."

This was the belief of the community at [Qumran](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qumran) shortly before the destruction of the Second Temple. They are often compared with Essenes and/or followers of John the Baptist, but identifying those groups with each other is controversial. Similar, though not identical, beliefs about multiple messiahs existed in the Second Temple period, as in the apocryphal Testament of the Twelve Tribes (citations to similar passages can be found in [this article](http://www.livius.org/articles/religion/messiah/messiah-9-two-messiahs/)).